# Macro loop through all files in a folder

Tags: vba

Im trying to get a macro to loop through all the files in a folder and run a macro on it. So far I have:

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim Filename, Pathname As String
    Dim Wb As Workbook

    Pathname = "C:\Trading\TICK\PROBAB\DATA\CURRENT\"
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsm")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.Open (Pathname & Filename)
        Application.Run "storage.xlsm!ALL"
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop


End Sub
```

The problem is, after the first iteration it fails. I know it is something to do with the second macro, as if I take it out, all the files in the folder will open.

Comment: **I know it is something to do with the second macro** Then perhaps you should show that code?

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie  What would that accomplish? if OP removes that, then there is no Loop structure.

Comment: Also, by "it fails", what do you mean? Is there an error? And if so, what line raises the error and what *specific* error message is given?

Comment: When I say the second macro I mean the nested macro eg "Application.run "storage.xlsm!ALL, it is in the code above

Comment: I have tried removing the Fielname=Dir() but this did not do anything

Comment: It stops the macro and when I debug, the line: "Workbooks.Open (Pathname & Filename)" is highlighted in yellow

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was related to the short term memory Excel has. The macro was doing a large amount of copy and pasting and it seems it was somehow prohibiting it from opening the next file.

I solved the problem by creating a new file with the same macro. It is working now