# How to obtain the data from cell from 500 .xls Excel files?

Tags: vba, excel, xls

I'd like to ask you how can I get the data from few determined (and always same) cells from many Excel `.xls` files, I.e. I have a list of `.xls` files in one folder, and each file has the same table inside, but with the different values. I would like to obtain the data from `A1`, `C2`, `E3` from all files in folder and put them together into a new table in the new Excel file.

Is there a way how to do it, please? :) Thanks! ;)

Comment: Yes there is a way. Have a look at this for looping through files in a folder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354315/macro-loop-through-all-files-in-a-folder . Then record a macro to see how to obtain the values from specific cells.

Answer (score 2):

I retrieve external data as follows:

Create a worksheet called *"x"* that specifies the following info for each item of data I want to get:

[image: info]

So I have the folder name, the file name, the worksheet name, and the cell reference for the items in columns **A, B, C, D**

Then run the following macro:

```
Sub GetExternalData()

    Dim wbPath As String, WorkbookName As String
    Dim WorksheetName As String, CellRef As String
    Dim Ret As String, i As Long, N As Long

    For i = 1 To Sheets("x").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        wbPath = Sheets("x").Cells(i, 1).Value
        WorkbookName = Sheets("x").Cells(i, 2).Value
        WorksheetName = Sheets("x").Cells(i, 3).Value
        CellRef = Sheets("x").Cells(i, 4).Value

        Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & WorkbookName & "]" & _
              WorksheetName & "'!" & Range(CellRef).Address(True, True, -4150)

        Sheets("x").Cells(i, 5).Value = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Ret)
    Next i
End Sub
```

The macro will fill column **E** with the data.

In your case column **A** will be filled with replicated values since your files are all in a single folder.