# How to use a cell as a filename in a reference in excel?

Tags: excel

If I have a cell, "`a2`" which has part of a filename/filepath, "`sheet2.xlsx`" in it which I want to use as a reference another workbook, how can I accomplish this?

I have tried using the `INDIRECT` function but always get a reference error.

I am trying to find a way to summarize a list of spreadsheets with column `a` containing the spreadsheet name and another column referencing a cell inside that respective sheet.

Comment: The referenced workbook must be **open** for *INDIRECT()* to work.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Is there another function similar that can fit my needs or should I just do it manually?

Comment: I ended up using option one given by [this comment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.excel.worksheet.functions/lzqhzexSvH4/dQAPVlM3RKwJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the referenced workbook is **open**, then here is an example of getting a value from it:

```
=INDIRECT( "'" & A1 & "[" & B1 & "]" & C1 & "'!" & D1)
```

where the components are like:

[image]

Note we have specified:

1. the path
2. the filename
3. the worksheet name
4. the cell address

If the file is **not open**, you can still retrieve data with a ***ExecuteExcel4Macro***  *(assuming you have a version of Excel that supports this function)*  For an example of this type of code, see:

[Get Data from External Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094694/how-to-obtain-the-data-from-cell-from-500-xls-excel-files/25095129%20-%2025095129)