# add a variable to filename 'filename'+A2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

This is what I have right now:

```
=(SUM(IF('C:\file(1808).xls]Page 1'!$G$2:$G$379=A17;1;0)))
```

How do I get it to work like this?:

```
=(SUM(IF('C:\file(A17).xls]Page 1'!$G$2:$G$379=A17;1;0)))
```

Comment: please try like this `INDIRECT("'[C:\file(" & A17 & ").xls]Page 1'!$G$2:$G$379")`.

Comment: INDIRECT("'[C:\file name(" & A17 & ").xls]Page 1'!$G$2:$G$379")

Gives a REF error even tough the file name is correct and linking working.

Comment: (INDIRECT((SUM(IF("'C:\file name(" & A50 & ").xls]Page 1'!$G$2:$G$379"=A31;1;0)))))
Same REF error.

Comment: i believe indirect only works if the workbook in question is open.  What I did notice above is you are missin a `[` which should probably just before `C:\...`

Comment: (SUM(IF(INDIRECT("'C:\File name ("&B49&").xls]Page 1'!G2:G379")=A31;1;0)))
Got it working like this.
Yeah it needs to be open.

Found some help from these.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34233001/how-to-use-a-cell-as-a-filename-in-a-reference-in-excel

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094694/how-to-obtain-the-data-from-cell-from-500-xls-excel-files/25095129%20-%2025095129